# how to address a week 0, month 0, in a time dimension in ssas

Tags: ssas, mdx, hierarchy

I have a time dimension which, for funky reasons, needs to have the first fiscal week of 2012 be week 0, which requires a month 0 and a quarter 0.  (This is because the retail fiscal calendar for 2012 has an extra week to adjust for the week drift.)  The time dimension table was changed a while ago to reflect that, so that we can make fiscal month, week, and day comparisons to the correct periods.  (I assume that anyone who works in retail will have experienced this).

I have a measure to retrieve the last year's period values, defined this way:

```
(parallelperiod([Time Order Date].[Order Date Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year Name], 1, 
[Time Order Date].[Order Date Fiscal Hierarchy].CurrentMember), 
[Measures].[Product Rev (with ship, with disc)])
```

This is not working.  Fiscal month 1 of 2013 is mapping to the value for fiscal month 0 2012, and so on, with frequent nulls, and nothing seems to match.

I'm not surprised that this throwing the system for a loop.  But I don't know how to fix it.

(FWIW, I have a different way of displaying the data, which involves two different fiscal time dimensions, which display the data properly.  But I am trying to make it work the "conventional" way.)

--sw